# Cut directory when dragging

Tags: directory, filemanager

It seems to me the default behavior when dragging a directory to a new location has suddenly changed in my Ubuntu. It used to cut the directory, now it just copies it.

Where could I change this?

Comment: If you are dragging *across storage devices* (SSD ⇢ HDD, Local ⇢ Network), then it will copy. If you are dragging across directories on the same storage device, then it's a move.

Comment: It did not change, it has always been like that.

Comment: Holding down one of Ctrl or Alt or Shift changes what happens when you drag (I don't remember what each keys does, but one forces copying, one forces moving, and one forces linking)

Comment: Thanks all! I believe the cause was what @matigo pointed out, I'll pay more attention to these details about the storage device

Answer (score 0):

It did not change... It has always been like that! (See the cases below.)

- If you are dragging across storage devices and/or environments: `([SSD, HDD] ⇢ [SSD, HDD], [Local, Network] ⇢ [Local, Network])`, then it will **`copy`**.
- If you are dragging across directories/folders on the same storage device, then it will **`move`**.

As you are now aware of this, there's no issue anymore.